# How do I send a message to an I/O address in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, serial-port

I have a Windows XP machine that is connected to a cash drawer via an RJ12 cable.

As per the manufacturer's instructions here:
http://www.aures-support.fr/UK/faq/galeo/
the cash drawer is on I/O address of HEX 4B8 (decimal 1208).

There is software running on the PC that opens the drawer correctly, plus the testing scripts provided by the manufacturer's website also work. This indicates that the drivers must be working correctly. And the manufacturer's defaults are all there.

How can I send a message to the I/O address to test this, and with what script/method should I do this? Command line?

(As per the link, in the device manager there is a "prolific COM port", on COM7. I've tried testing the drawer by sending a message to COM7 from both the command line and using JS with a nodejs script running. Neither have worked. This makes me think that simply addressing the COM7 port by name is not enough, and that I need the exact I/O address. I'm happy to be corrected on this assumption.)

Much appreciated.

Comment: You don't "send a message", you simply write a byte to the I/O port.  It takes a single machine code instruction, OUT DX,AL.  Plus a driver that reconfigures the OS to allow a user-mode program to use that instruction.  That test program is not theirs, DriverLynx's DLPORTIO is one of many freeware utilities, Logix4u's INPOUT32 is very common.  Just google these names and you'll find lots of hits.

Comment: Create a plain text file with your message and name it e.g. `test.txt`; go to command-line window, `mode COM7: 9600,N,8,1` and then `copy test.txt COM7:`; let us know all output from those commands, please